# Django request.is_ajax returning false

Tags: ajax, django

I am testing out ajax with Django + jQuery. I have this in my views:

```
def ajax_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "This is ajax"
    else:
        message = "Not ajax"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

and this in my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$.get("/ajax_test", function(data) {
    alert(data);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is - why does this return "Not ajax" to my html page?

Comment: Note that `is_ajax` is deprecated in Django 3.1 and will be removed in a later version.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't know what happened to you. I tested and got a good message: `This is ajax`. My code:

**urls.py**

```py
url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.home', name='home'),
url(r'^ajax_test/$', 'myapp.views.ajax_test', name='ajax_test'),
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html', {},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def ajax_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "This is ajax"
    else:
        message = "Not ajax"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

**templates/home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.get("/ajax_test/", function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looking at your code, I realize that my error was that I needed two views. One for the template (`home.html`) and one which is called by the ajax function (`ajax_test.html`). When I adjusted my code to work thus, I got the desired result. I'm not sure if it is always necessary to have this separation of the views but it works for me and seems logical.

Answer (score 21):

Looks like `is_ajax` just checks the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` (looks like `X-Requested-With` in HTTP) header. If it equals `XMLHttpRequest`, we have an ajax query.

So it's pretty easy now to trace the fate of this header:

1. Look at the initial HTTP request (using browser's debug plugin, Wireshark, tcpdump or any other tool you prefer) and see if it has a correct `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header. If it doesn't, the problem is with jQuery (or your script).
2. The header can be lost during redirection, as Daniel Roseman said (haven't seen this myself, but almost sure it's possible). You'll see two (or more) chained HTTP requests in this case, and one of them will lack the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header. In this case, the problem could be with the webserver's config or redirection itself (you may have to get rid of it or manually relay the header if redirection response is generated by your code).
3. Also, HTTP proxies can cut headers. In this case you may look at the HTTP request on the server side via traffic inspector or `request.environ` (pretty garbled with environment vars, but HTTP headers are also there).

Comment: for me, the uppercase doesn't work, this works:
{
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    }

Comment: Indeed, I just copied the key as Django sees it (from django/http/request.py) and forgot that it could be mangled and looks differently on the wire.

Comment: Thanks. That's the root of the problem. Using Axios I had to do the following: `axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';`

Answer (score 6):

Probably you've got APPEND_SLASH turned on (the default), and Django is redirecting from `/ajax_test` to `/ajax_test/` but not preserving the relevant header. Better to request the version with the slash in the first place.

Comment: Sorry - that didn't make any difference.

Comment: Hmm, I'm stumped then, I'm afraid. Maybe try dumping the request headers to the log, see what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Adjusted my code to the following:

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html',
                            locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 

def ajax_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "This is ajax"
    else:
        message = "Not ajax"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',   
    #    root
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'), 
    #    ajax
    url(r'^ajax_test/$', views.ajax_test, name='ajax_test'),
)
```

template:

```
 ...
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready( function() {
     $.get("/ajax_test/", function(data) {
        alert(data);
     });
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with other version of jQuery... it possible that the problem was in the js...

For example:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score -2):

In your `.get` call, you must specify the CSRF Token. I don't know if this is the problem, but should help.

```
.get(..., function(data) {

    (...)
    data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
    (...)
})
```

Comment: incorrect or missing csrf token will return 403, this has nothing to do with is_ajax

Comment: if you are fetching data from your backend, it does not need a csrf_token, it's only required on post