# django request.is_ajax returns false

Tags: javascript, python, django, jquery

i can't understand why  my view returns false for request.is_ajax
here is the relevant code
in views.py

```
def ajax_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "This is an Ajax message"
    else:
        message = "Ajax error"
    return render_to_response("ajax.html",
        context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'message':message}))
```

in ajax.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#click_me').bind('click',function(){

            $.get('#');

        });

    });
```

i have a template variable `{{ message }}` which is supposed to be updated to "This is an Ajax message" when i click on the click_me link. But that is not happening. i have read all the relevant questions here but can't figure out what is going wrong.
thanks

Comment: Use developer tools to make sure the request is sent with the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header containing `'XMLHttpRequest'`

Comment: you say "But that is not happening". What does happen? Do you see the text "Ajax error"?

Comment: i have checked Http headers in firefox(installed LiveHttpheaders plugin) and i can see the header X-Requested-with is set to 'XMLHttprequest'; and yes i always see "Ajax error", thanks

Comment: Do you get a fresh response? What does $.get('#') do anyway? Maybe the browser does pull the page from cache?

Comment: i do get a fresh response. To make it clear i have one template ajax.html with a variable {{ message }} and an anchor tag pointing to the same url '/ajax_test/' , rendered by a view that i have posted.when i visit the url i get "Ajax error" that's ok, but i expected to get "This is an Ajax message" when i click the link click me, instead when i click the link the page reloads and still displays "Ajax error" but this time i do see that i get a fresh response and X-Requested-With is set to XMLHttpResponse

Comment: similar question answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587693/django-request-is-ajax-returning-false  but it works when i have two templates,, what is it that i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ajax request gets a 3xx redirect response, and the `X-Requested-with` header is gone ?

It is not clear what `$.get('#')` does.

That's a common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i can answer my own question,but got it solved, and yes, i don't have an idea,
what the $.get('#') does,i just tried to visit the same url by doing so,here is how it worked

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#click_me').bind('click',function(){
            $('#insert_here').load("/ajax_test/ #insert_here");
            return false;
        });
```

and the relevant html (i am sorry i rally don't know how to include html code in this editor)
in p element there is `{{ message }}` with id 'insert_here' and an a tag with id click_me and
href attribute '/ajax_test/',
thus when i visit the url '/ajax_test/' i get "Ajax error" and when i click the link i get "This is an Ajax message",if i don't use return false it returns "Ajax error".
i really don't have an idea what the return false does,thanks for the responses