# Django JSON not sending proper data

Tags: python, json, django

I am developing a django python web application. In my webpage, I am sending a request to my API by sending a 'term' and my API is supposed to return the 'content' field of the search.

My content contains 'xxx is good' in my database.

Here is my code in views.py

```
def get_RuleStatement(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')
        rule_statements = RuleStatement.objects.filter(content__icontains = q )[:1]
        results = []
        for rule_statement in rule_statements:
            rule_statement_json = {}
            rule_statement_json['content'] = rule_statement.content
            results.append(rule_statement_json)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

For some reason, whenever I send the following request: http://website.com/api/get_RuleStatement/?term=xxx

It returns 'fail' even through my database contains data 'xxx is good'. Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: Apparently, `request.is_ajax()` is false. The answers to [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587693/django-request-is-ajax-returning-false) might help. How are you sending the request when you test? It must have a certain header in order for it to appear to be an ajax request. Specifically the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header must be equal to "XMLHttpRequest".

Comment: I am sending an ajax request from my webpage

Answer (score 0):

The only reason possible for it is `is_ajax()` is return False. That means your are not making the `AJAX` request. I believe you are making normal HTTP call to your endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

See the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax) and check that your HTTP request has the HTTP header `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` set with the string 'XMLHttpRequest'.  Then `request.is_ajax()` will return `True`.

Note modern libraries like jQuery will automatically set this HTTP header for you; e.g., if you get jquery and do

```
<script>
$.get('/api/get_RuleStatement', {'term': 'xxx'})
</script>
```

Alternatively, you can get rid of the `if request.is_ajax():` line and make it

```
def get_RuleStatement(request):
    q = request.GET.get('term', '')
    rule_statements = RuleStatement.objects.filter(content__icontains = q)[:1]
    results = []
    for rule_statement in rule_statements:
        results.append({'content': rule_statement.content})
    data = json.dumps(results)
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

if you don't care about it being an ajax call and want to be able to see the response otherwise.  Also you may want to consider using [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) instead of HttpResponse so you don't have to serialize or set MIME-type yourself.  E.g.,

```
def get_RuleStatement(request):
    q = request.GET.get('term', '')
    rule_statements = RuleStatement.objects.filter(content__icontains = q)[:1]
    results = []
    for rule_statement in rule_statements:
        results.append({'content': rule_statement.content})
    return JsonResponse(results, safe=False) 
           # the safe = False is neccessary when
           # you serialize non-dicts like results which is a list
```