# django not identifing ajax, and not able to post

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

Found on questions on `is_ajax`- [Django request.is_ajax returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587693/django-request-is-ajax-returning-false#8588090) - but that does not solve anything for me. I'm working around this by using 'ajax' in the GET...

I'm also trying to post through AJAX, but I can't find the results.

My AJAX handler is this:

```
function getContent(pageGet,method,post,target) {
    if (typeof(post)   ==='undefined') post   = "";
    if (typeof(method) ==='undefined') method = "GET";
    if (typeof(target) ==='undefined') target = "body";
    pageGet = '/?ajax=home/'+pageGet.replace('?','&');
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var body = document.getElementById(target);
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            if (this.status == 200) {
                body.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                var scripts = body.getElementsByTagName("script");
                var script_amount = scripts.length;
                for( var i = 0; i < script_amount; ++i)
                    eval(scripts[i].innerHTML);
            } else if (this.status == 0) {
                getContent('main.html');
            } else {
                body.innerHTML =  "Failed with "+this.status;
            }
        }
    };
    xhttp.open(method, pageGet, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(post);
    return false;
}
```

As, I said this never registers in `is_ajax`, but AJAX is working fine. This is the value of `pageGet`:

```
/?ajax=home/forms/genericForm.html&form=UserForm
```

and this the value of `post`:

```
username=sdf&password=dfs&=Submit&
```

Obviously `method`="POST".

This gets to my view.py, and the `request.GET` is populated properly with 'ajax' (my workaround for the other problem), and 'form'. But `request.POST` is empty, as well as `request.body` which is alluded to here - [Ajax POST not sending data when calling 'request.POST' in Django view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532573/ajax-post-not-sending-data-when-calling-request-post-in-django-view#34533451) and some other answer.

There are also mentions of a "CSRF" token, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The view code just prints request.`GET,body`, and `POST`, and `is_ajax`.

**Please, only pure JS solutions.**

**Progress**

I managed to get post to work - by default CSRF is enabled, and you must set the AJAX header with it. If anyone figures the `is_ajax` part I'd be obliged.

Comment: try sending  `application/form-data` as header

Comment: @ArpitSolanki No luck, thanks, though.

Comment: did you try jquery ajax calls rather than xmlhttprequest

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I will not use JQuery for this, and no reason I should. Pure JS only.