# How to use Ajax in Django for like button

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I want to Ajax feature for the like button in my blog. I have implemented like feature first, it was working as expected(reloads page after clicking like button). Then, i want to implement Ajax so the page should not reload after clicking like button. But, it is not working as expected.

views.py:

```
def like_post(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_id = request.POST.get('id')
        post_obj = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)

        if user in post_obj.liked.all():
            post_obj.liked.remove(user)
        else:
            post_obj.liked.add(user)

        like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=user, post_id=post_id)

        if not created:
            if like.value == 'Like':
                like.value = 'Unlike'
            else:
                like.value = 'Like'

        like.save()
    if request.is_ajax():
        post = Post.objects.all()
        context={
        'post': post
        }
        html = render_to_string('blog/like_section.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

Jquery in base.html:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(event){
            $(document).on('click', '#like', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("hello")
                var pk = $(this).attr('value');
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : {% url 'like-post' %},
                    data : {'id' : pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'}, 
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success : function(response){
                        $('#like-section').html(response['form'])
                        console.log($('#like-section').html(response['form']));
                    },
                    error : function(rs, e){
                        console.log(rs.responseText);
                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

like_section.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'like-post' %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}">
      {% if user not in post.liked.all %}
        <button id="like" class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" type="submit">Like</button>
      {% else %}
        <button id="like" class="btn btn-info mb-4" type="submit">Unlike</button>
      {% endif %}
</form>
```

urls.py:

```
path('likes/', views.like_post, name='like-post'),
```

It returns 404 with No Post matches the given query. My observation is, it looks it is not detecting Jquery part because if I replace `'id'` with `'post_id'` in `request.POST.get('id')` & `return redirect` under `request.method == 'POST'`, it works like my previous version(Reloads page if I hit like button). So the control never goes into `request.is_ajax()` loop, How do I make Django to use Ajax?

Comment: Check in your network tab if `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` is  added in header

Comment: No.....it's not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587693/django-request-is-ajax-returning-false