# Following a tutorial I got a view retuning None instead because is_ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django, ajax

I just started with ajax but can't seem to find the fix for this. I think it might have to do with the comment_id vs the blog_id. (followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoWw1Y5qqt8&list=PLKILtxhEt4-RT-GkrDkJDLuRPQfSK-6Yi&index=39&ab_channel=AbhishekVerma).

This is what my views.py looks like

```
def like_comment(request):
comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, id=request.POST.get("comment_id"))
blog = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, id=request.POST.get("blog_id"))
comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=blog, reply=None)
if request.user in comment.likers.all():
    comment.likers.remove(request.user)
else:
    comment.likers.add(request.user)
context = {
    "comments": comments,
    "blog_post": blog,
    "body": markdown2.markdown(blog.body),
    "comment_form": CommentForm(),
}

if request.is_ajax():
    html = render_to_string('blog/like_section.html',
                            context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

This is a snippet of my HTML

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %} 
 <form action={% url 'like_comment' %} method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if user in comment.likers.all %}
<input type="hidden" name="blog_id" value=" {{ blog_post.id }}">
<button type="submit" id="like" name="comment_id" value="{{ comment.id }}">Like</button>
{% else %}
<input type="hidden" name="blog_id" value=" {{ blog_post.id }}">
<button type="submit" id="like" name="comment_id" value="{{ comment.id }}">Dislike</button>
{% endif %}
{% else %}
<div><small class="comment_time">Login to Like</small></div>
{% endif %}
</form>
 </div>
 <small class="comment_time">{{ comment.total_likes }}
Likes</small>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
        $(document).on('click', '#like', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var pk = $(this).attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '{% url "like_comment" %}',
                data: { 'blog_id': pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#like_section').html(response['form'])
                    console.log($('#like_section').html(response['form']));
                },
                error: function (rs, e) {
                    console.log(rs.responseText);
                },
            });
        });
    });
```

I'm getting the following error:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUR2m.png)

Comment: maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587693/django-request-is-ajax-returning-false

Comment: @Razenstein I already looked at that thread, but didn't find anything useful, might be because I don't understand it fully though

Answer (score 0):

I would start to check if the request header contains HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest'. You can do that with the debug function of the browser (e.g. firefox). Maybe your JS library does not send this header.

see the Django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax

```
 def is_ajax(self):
        return self.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

HttpRequest.is_ajax():

Returns True if the request was made via an XMLHttpRequest, by checking the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header for the string 'XMLHttpRequest'. Most modern JavaScript libraries send this header. If you write your own XMLHttpRequest call (on the browser side), you’ll have to set this header manually if you want is_ajax() to work.

If a response varies on whether or not it’s requested via AJAX and you are using some form of caching like Django’s cache middleware, you should decorate the view with vary_on_headers('X-Requested-With') so that the responses are properly cached.